# done is not a function error in passport js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using passportjs for the authentication and session. I get the ussername from mysql and the input field from client side but when the `done` is called on verification, I get `done is not a function`.

The server.js :

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

// app.use(app.router);
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/staticFolder"));

var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'127.0.0.1',
    user:'root',
    password:'sdf',
    database:'abc'
});
connection.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
    console.log("serializeUser" + user);
    done(null,user.body.username);
})
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
     done(null, user);

 });


passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback : true

},function(username, password, done) {

    connection.query("select * from employeedetails where empid = "+username.body.username,function(err,user,w){
    if(err)
    {
        console.log(err+"fml $$$$$$$$$$");  
         return done(err);           
    }
    if(username.body.password == user[0].password){
    console.log(user[0].empid+" login");
     return done(null,user[0].empid);
  }
  else{
     return done(null,false,{message: 'Incorrect password'});
   console.log(user[0].empid+" fml"); 
  }

  });

}));



app.get('/',function(request,response){
    response.sendFile(__dirname+"/staticFolder/view/");
})

app.post('/saveEmployeeDetails',function(request,response){
    response.end();
})

app.get('/login',function(request,response){ //the file sent when /login is requested
    response.sendFile(__dirname+"/staticFolder/view/login.html");
})

app.post('/loginCheck',passport.authenticate('local', {
            successRedirect : '/', 
            failureRedirect : '/login', 
            failureFlash : true // 
    }),
        function(req, res) {
            console.log("hello");
            res.send("valid");
            res.redirect('/');
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you please refer to the below link which talks about the same error

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/421

It says when you remove the (passReqToCallBack: true) options the error does not occur

Comment: how to pass the request object then?

Comment: This is an optional parameter and you may or may pass it. In your case if you are getting the error try removing the optional parameter and see if it works...

passReqToCallback`  when `true`, `req` is the first argument to the verify callback (default: `false`)

Answer (score 1):

In your passport.js config file, passport.use(new LocalStrategy) callback
function depending on which strategy you are using you will need a certain number of arguments.I just had to add "req"
as the first argument in mine.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback: true
},
function (req, apikey, done) {
    //ADD REQ UP HERE
    process.nextTick(function () {
        findByApiKey(apikey, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Unknown apikey : ' + apikey
                });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        })
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be an issue of missing parameters in the function.
Here is an example source code for `passport-openidconnect` strategy:

```
// Using 'passport-openidconnect' strategy
var OpenidConnectStrategy = require('passport-openidconnect');

var strategy = new OpenidConnectStrategy(
  {
    issuer: process.env.OAUTH_ISSUER,
    authorizationURL: process.env.OAUTH_AUTHORIZATION_URL,
    tokenURL: process.env.OAUTH_TOKEN_URL, 
    userInfoURL: process.env.OAUTH_USERINFO_URL,
    clientID: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL,
  },
  // Parameters in the function should be appropriate with the strategy
  function (issuer, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, done) {
    return done(null, profile);
  }
);
```