# Issue in saving registered user to MongoDB in Node JS - Express application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am new to Node.js and trying to create a chat application program. For that I have created a Signup registration form with express framework. The data will be saved in MongoDB. Application uses passport middleware signup functionality. Issue is when submitting a new user for second time I am not able to see the data in mongoDB, instead i can see only the first data. I set the mongodb debug option to true, after submitting the form, user submitted data will be seen through console.

Please see the github code which i created: https://github.com/Deepesh316/jabarchat

Please see the mongodb user details getting saved data code: passport-local.js

```
passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, (req, email, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({'email': email}, (err, user) => {

        // Network or Internet connection error
        if(err) {
            return done(err);
        }

        if(user) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'User with email already exist'));
        }

        // Creating new instance of user and save it to database

        const newUser = new User();
        newUser.username = req.body.username;
        newUser.email = req.body.email;
        newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(req.body.password);

        newUser.save((err) => {
            done(null, newUser);
        });
    });
}));
```

Below is the code snippet for Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, unique: true },
    fullname: { type: String, unique: true, default: ''},
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, default: ''},
    userImage: { type: String, default: 'default.png'},
    facebook: { type: String, default: ''},
    fbTokens: Array,
    google: { type: String, default: ''},
    googleTokens: Array
});

userSchema.methods.encryptPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
};

userSchema.methods.validUserPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: You are submitting different data for username, fullname and email, right ?

Comment: @eduPeeth Yes different username.

Comment: `By default, LocalStrategy expects to find credentials in parameters named username and password`
It seems that the arguments are `email` `password` and `done` not `req`, `email`, `password` and `done`
http://www.passportjs.org/docs/username-password/

Comment: @t3__rry Can you please help me to make modification in code? I tried to remove req. Then I got an error like done is not a function.

Comment: Take a look at those URL which may help you solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031493/done-is-not-a-function-error-in-passport-js
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/421

Comment: @t3__rry But this url is working. https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local and one of the links i referred is this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is saying that there's already a record with null as the fullname. In other words, you already have a user without an fullname.

The relevant documentation for this:

```
If a document does not have a value for the indexed field in a unique index, the index will store a null value for this document. Because of the unique constraint, MongoDB will only permit one document that lacks the indexed field. If there is more than one document without a value for the indexed field or is missing the indexed field, the index build will fail with a duplicate key error.

You can combine the unique constraint with the sparse index to filter these null values from the unique index and avoid the error.


Sparse indexes only contain entries for documents that have the indexed field, even if the index field contains a null value.
```

In other words, a sparse index is ok with multiple documents all having null values.

Check with mydb.users.getIndexes() if this is the case and manually remove the unwanted index with mydb.users.dropIndex()